# React Native API Calls to .NET Core backend only work when React Native Debugger Network Inspect Enabled

Tags: .net, react-native

I am creating a project with a React Native front end and a .NET Core backend. Right now I am using Visual Studio to run the backend server, and the base URL for the API calls is `https://localhost:5001`. I am testing on an Android Emulator with Android Studio. The problem is that the API calls will only work when the React Native Debugger network inspect feature is enabled. Other than that, it just gives me `Error: Network Error` in the console. I have tried putting my own IP address instead of `localhost`, as well as trying to change `localhost` to `10.0.2.2`. Neither of those work. Does anyone know of a fix for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You did your call with axios ?
if yes try to use fetch i think the problem comes with https

Comment: Yeah I have tried both Axios and fetch, with both https and http. It is the same result any way I do it.

Comment: Try to add '/' at the end of your API request, i found this in some forums may be it fix the issue , sometimes we need to do stupid things

Comment: That didn't work either. I guess I will just have to have the network insepct turned on when testing locally.